# How to loop iframe in angular 8

Tags: angular

Iframe reloading all the time.
Is there any way to stop reloading?

Mycode

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let element of elements">
<iframe
      [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(element?.src)"
      width="500"
      height="500"
>
</iframe>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: please provide a working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) as its still unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I think the issue here is as you are passing ResouceUrl it is of type string it resets the iframe changeDetection everytime the browser loads try using custom Directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that ypu are binding on a function. Angular does not know when the function value updates (it binds to a reference) so you have this issue. Same thing will happen with a getter.

My suggestion is that you do the following:

Create a member variable in your component

```
 public elementSrc = [];
```

Assign in the code the source in your init function, or wherever you change the value.

```
 // For each of your elements
 this.elementSrc[i] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(element[i]?.src)
```

And assign in your code like this

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index">
<iframe
      [src]="elementSrc[i]"
      width="500"
      height="500"
>
</iframe>
</ng-container>
```

Another way you can go, is to sanitize the src for every element before binding and just bind with element.sanitizedSrc